# Is it required that a capacitor is marked X2?

Tags: capacitor

I want to replace a capacitor in a power supply.

The original is marked: `250V, 0.1, WIMA MP 3`. I bought one that says: `ERO MKT 1822 0,1 250V`. What bothers me is the safety rating X. Is the original one X2 ? What is `MP 3`? Do I need to buy another one that explicitly says X2 on it? I want to stay on the safe side.

Comment: Getting the safety rating of a capacitor in a power supply wrong can mean the difference between a **safe** and a **lethal** power supply. Ideally you would investigate what the function of that capacitor is to confirm what safety rating it needs to have. Read here about the safety ratings: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/safety-capacitor-class-x-and-class-y-capacitors/  If you lack the knowledge to judge what you need then either educate yourself before making any changes to a power supply.

Comment: Marking is most likely not required, but the capacitor must still be X2 rated.

Comment: As a general rule capacitors are marked at their maximum rated voltage UNLESS some special standard applies. In the case lf an X2 capacitor the actual rated voltage is substantially higher than marked value. | I'd expect a cap marked MKT 250V to be 250C DC rated. The data sheet should tell you. If it doesn't then it is utterly unsuitable (even if it's suitable :-) ).

Comment: The data sheets support my above statements. The KT cap appears to be 250 VDC and 160 VAC rated and gives no indication that it is X2 suitable at 160 VAC - nor even at 110  VAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the [Wima MP 3](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/440/e_WIMA_MP_3-X2-1139937.pdf) is this one (or similar): -

[image]

And it has "X2" written on it... then for the sake of peace of mind, choose a capacitor that is also rated as "X2" or better.

I don't see "X2" in the [data sheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2047457.pdf) for the MKT1822 device so, dig a little deeper and find one that you are confident about.

[image]

Comment: 250V MKT is 160 VAC rated - and not X2 even then.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon excellent point.